# What's the difference between the {% include ... %} tag and and the {% ssi ... parsed %} tag in Django templates?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

They seem to be basically the same EXCEPT that you have to give ssi an absolute path for "security reasons". Except for keyword arguments (which are new since version 1.3), the two seem to have exactly the same capabilities. Are they really redundant?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without the `parsed` parameter to `{% ssi %}` the included file won't be treated as a Django template, it will just be included as normal text. This means that if the included file had template tags/filters, they would not be interpreted.

When you *do* include the `parsed` parameter, the differences become more like what you said.

- There's added security restrictions with `{% ssi %}` since you can potentially include any file on the filesystem.
- You must use an absolute URI rather than a relative path suitable for a template loader.
- Until Django 1.5, the first argument (the path) must be unquoted. This means you cannot use a template variable as the first argument.

There's more details on the last point in [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/templates/builtins/#ssi).

Comment: ok, so they're different when you don't use the `parsed' flag, but what about when you DO use it??

Comment: I still don't see the point of the ssi tag. Is it just so that you can include files that aren't listed in TEMPLATE_DIRS? Why would you do that??

PS: I read the documentation before posting this question. The description there does not mention specific differences.

Comment: To be honest I think it's mostly a legacy tag that hasn't been removed for backwards compatibility sake (which is a high priority in Django). It's not a tag I've ever used in production.

Comment: it also allow to include without creating new rendering process. if you have to include rows of a big table, ssi will be "more efficient" as it will not start as many renderer than rows.